# How to get a dynamic elements height in console

Tags: jquery, console

Stupid question I know but can't seem to get this working. Using Chrome console, I need to get the height of some elements (can do with inspector, but this has become personal)

```
console.log$('#myDiv').height();
```

returns TypeError: Object # has no method 'log$'

```
console.log $('#myDiv').height();
```

returns SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

I know this is simple, and Ive looked around but cant see the forrest for the trees at this point.

Comment: console.log is a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
console.log( $('#myDiv').height() )
```

`console.log` is a function so you need parentheses to call it, passing as argument(s) what you want to output in the console.

If typing directly into the console directly, you can omit `console.log`:

```
$('#myDiv').height()
```

The console automatically returns the last return value to your screen so you don't have to `console.log` when using the console.

Comment: 'Doh thanks guys! both answers are correct, choosing the first as accepted. "The console automatically returns the last return value to your screen so you don't have to console.log when using the console." man im a genius

Answer (score 2):

Try: `console.log($('#myDiv').height());`

(You were missing the parenthesis)